# (mips64) lw and sw not adding value to registers

Tags: assembly, mips64

I am new to mips and for a homework project we have to convert a C code into mips64 assembly and run it with winmips64. The C code is this:

```
void fir(int X[], int H[], int Y[], int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;
    int y0;

    for (j=0; j<m; j++){
        y0=0;
        for (i=0; i<n; i++){
            y0+=X[i+j]*H[i];
        }
        Y[j]=y0;
    }
}
```

The lines I am having a problem with are `y0+=X[i+j]*H[i]` and `Y[j]=y0`, this is my attempt at doing them:

```
for2:
    beq r7,r3, afterfor2                        # for(i=0, i<n, i++)

    #making X[i+j]
    dadd r8,r5,r7                               # i+j stored in r8
    dmul r9,r8,r18                              #(i+j)*8 to find address stored in r8r9
    lw r10, r9(r0)                               #load x[i+j] to r10

    #making H[i]
    dmul r11,r18,r7                             # 8*i
    lw r12,r11(r1)                              #load h[i] to r12

    dmul r13,r10,r12                            #x[i+j] * h[i]
    dadd r6,r6,r13                              #y0 = y0 + x[i+j]*h[i]
    daddi r7,r7,1                               # i++
    j for2                                      # repeat loop

afterfor2: 
        
    dmul r14,r5,r18                             #8*j stored to r14
    sw r6, r14(r2)                              #Y[j] = y0
    daddi r5,r5,1                               #j++
    
    j for1                                      #go back to start of loop for1
```

More specifically these lines because no values are added to registers `r10,r6`, and `r12`:

```
lw r10, r9(r0)                               #load x[i+j] to r10
lw r12,r11(r1)                               #load h[i] to r12
sw r6, r14(r2)                               #Y[j] = y0
```

The winmips64 documentation mentions that I need to use an immediate to store/load to and from the arrays but how am I supposed to do it when I don't know the immediate and instead the values are based on adding and multiplying the indexes? don't they have to be stored in a register?

Thank you for your help in advance

edit: the code in total

```
.data                                           #data segment
    X: .word 1,1,1,2,2,3,4,2,1,1,2,3,2,4,8,1    #X[]
    H: .word 1,5,1,4,2,1,1,1                    #H[]
    Y: .space 64                                #n*8 = 8*8 = 64 bytes reserved for the y0 results = R2

    n: .word 8                                  #n = 8
    m: .word 8                                  #m = 8

   

.text
fir:                                            #void fir
    
    ori r15, r0, X                             #address of X[]
    ori r1, r0, H                              #address of H[]
    ori r2, r0, Y                              #address of Y[]

    daddi r3,r3,8                               # n = r3 = 8
    daddi r4,r4,8                               # m = r4 = 8

    dadd r5,r0,r0                              #set j counter to 0
    daddi r18,r0,8                                  

    j for1                                      #go to for1 loop

for1:   
    beq r5,r4,exit                              #when j is equal to m loop stops and goes to the exit function
    dadd r6,r0,r0                               #y0 = r6 = 0
    dadd r7,r0,r0                               #set i counter to 0 for every loop

    bne r5,r4,for2                              #go to the nested loop for2

for2:
    beq r7,r3, afterfor2                        # for(i=0, i<n, i++)

    #making X[i+j]
    dadd r8,r5,r7                               #i+j stored in r8
    dmul r9,r8,r18                              #(i+j)*8 to find address stored in r9
    daddu r9,r9,r15
    ld r10,(r9)                                 #load x[i+j] to r10

    #making H[i]
    dmul r11,r18,r7                             #8*i
    daddu r11,r11,r1                            #adding 8*i to the base address
    ld r12,(r11)                                #load h[i] to r12

    dmul r13,r10,r12                            #x[i+j] * h[i]
    dadd r6,r6,r13                              #y0 = y0 + x[i+j]*h[i]
    daddi r7,r7,1                               # i++
    j for2                                      # repeat loop

afterfor2: 
        
    dmul r14,r5,r18                             #8*j stored to r14
    daddu r14,r14,r2
    sd r6,(r14)                                 #Y[j] = y0
    daddi r5,r5,1                               #j++
    
    j for1                                      #go back to start of loop for1


exit:
    halt                                        #exit program
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such addressing mode as `register(register)`. You'll have to add the two registers together first.

For example, instead of `lw r12,r11(r1)`, do:

```
daddu r11,r11,r1
lw r12,(r11)
```

Note that in the case of `lw r10, r9(r0)`, you can simply replace that with `lw r10, (r9)`, since the value of `r0` is hardwired to 0.

Comment: i did like you said but running `lw r12,(r11)` didn't load `r11` (`h[i]`) to register `r12`, so `r12` remains with the value zero and the data cannot be stored. I also didn't know that `r0` was hardwired to the value zero so i change it to a different register to fix it, `r0` was supposed to be `x[]`.

Comment: Then one or more of those registers contains the wrong value, or your data is organized incorrectly. It's impossible for anyone else to say since you've only posted parts of your code. Use a debugger to step through the loop and verify that every register has the expected value at each instruction.

Comment: `r11` does have the correct value whenn running the loop it seems, but executing `lw r12, (r11)` doesn't add `r11`s value to `r12`.I posted the whole program in total but I am also looking into this further. thank you for your help

Comment: `ld r15,X(r0)` doesn't look like a correct way of loading the address of `X`. Same for the two instructions right after it. Use the `la` pseudo-instruction if your assembler supports it. Otherwise you may have to find out the exact addresses of those labels and load them with `lui` + `ori`.

Comment: WINMIPS64 didn't support the `la` instruction, but you were correct! `ld` didn't load the addresses of the arrays but instead their first value. Using the `ori` instruction worked! Thank you for bearing with me T-T